# All methods in one class or polymorphism implementation?

Tags: java, polymorphism, implementation

Here is what you need to know to understand the question:

1. I want to connect a class called SCL to a class called Region.
2. Now I have many different ways I want to connect a instance of
   these 2 classes.
3. Writing this is Java
4. There are no global variables in use

So I can either create several classes(about 9) that utilizes polymorphism but then each class has only one method called connect(...) with many different parameter lists. I think this is called a functor class.

For example a class "SCLToRegionOverlapCircleConnect" will have a connect method that looks like

```
public void connect(SCL scl, Region region, int radius, int overlapPercentage) {...}
```

while a class "RegionToRegionNonOverlapSquareConnect" will have a connect method that looks like

```
public void connect(Region bottomRegion, Region topRegion, int sideLength) {...}
```

OR

I can just make one class called ConnectionTypes and just have 9 different methods each with a different method signature.

What are the PROs and CONs of each implementation? Thanks!

Comment: Extensibility/maintainability/readability is in pretty big danger when working with the second solution.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman - No more than with the first, I would think.

Comment: What distinguishes one way of connecting from another? Do they behave differently, have different parameters, or are they just labeled differently? If the result of connecting is some sort of connection object, do the different ways of connecting produce different types of connection objects?

Comment: You don't go into details, but it seems odd that you can connect those two classes in 9 ways or more.  Maybe you should rethink everything.

Comment: `connect`?can you elaborate on it more..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use polymorphism, then you're determining the connection method when you instantiate the SCL object.  Does that make sense?  Or could an SCL class be connected to the Region in various different ways thoughout its life?  In that case, polymorphism doesn't make sense.  One important aspect that we have no information about is what happens to the parameters of the `connect(...)` method.  Do they need to be stored in the SCL class, in which case with different parameters polymorphism might again make sense so that each class can store the appropriate parameters.

Another thought is, is the act of connecting an SCL class to a region really a method for the SCL class at all, or should it live somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the second.

1. less classes, so the project is clarelier than in the other way.
2. you don't need to move 9 classes when you want to use your
   methods in another project (ex.), but only one class.
3. while programming, one rule is not to duplicate the code; using 9 classes,
   you have to write 9 times the declaration, and maybe to declare 9
   times the same global variables, using a lot more memory than using
   one.
4. overloading, that means that if you have to make one thing
   but in multiple ways (ex. you have to print some objects, and the
   result will be one string, but you need to write it different for
   one type of object, etc., you can use this technique) you can write
   9 methods with the same name, same output, but different inputs.
5. inheritance: if you want to make a class that inherits those
   methods, you MUST use only one class, because java does not support
   multiple inheritance.

I can't see any CONs, except that you have to reinitialize the global variables to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put two things straight:

- You are thinking of the Command pattern, not the Functor pattern. The difference is that the latter also has a method to retrieve the return value, but your `connect` method is void.
- The Functor pattern would not have a different signature for each of your `connect` methods; instead, each concrete class would have dedicated setters for the parameters (specific to the particular way you want to connect) and the same, parameterless `public void connect()` method. The latter would be the only method declared in the common `Connect` supertype.

I can throw in some example code if you want.

Pro: if it makes sense anywhere in your code to work with Connect commands without needing to know which of the 9 ways you're dealing with, then the Command pattern is your friend.

Con: you will have more code, and encapsulating pure functionality can reduce the understandability of your code quite a bit.